# How to render fieldset and legend tags only once (for 3 radio buttons output)

Tags: php, html, forms, oop, radio-button

I have a configuration php-file where I set an array with attributes for 3 radio buttons. In a Radio class I have a method called "render" that should output the radio buttons. The radio buttons shall be placed within a html fieldset tag.
Problem, I get the fieldset and legend tags for each radio button. But I want the radio buttons be embedded within 1 fieldset and 1 legend. I`m stuck.

This is the array configuration:

```
<?php
 $formConf = [
'kraken' => [
    'type' => 'radio',
    'id' => 'kraken',
    'name' => 'monster',
    'label' => 'Kraken',
    'radio' => 'checked'
],

'sasquatch' => [
    'type' => 'radio',
    'id' => 'sasquatch',
    'name' => 'monster',
    'label' => 'Sasquatch',
    'radio' => ''
],

'mothman' => [
    'type' => 'radio',
    'id' => 'mothman',
    'name' => 'monster',
    'label' => 'Mothman',
    'radio' => ''
]];
```

Here`s the Radio class:

```
class Radio extends Input {

protected $radio = ''; 
protected $legend = 'Choose your favorite monster';

public function __construct(array $opts)
{
    parent::__construct($opts);

    $this->type = 'radio';

    if (!isset($opts['radio']) || $opts['radio'] === '' || $opts['radio'] == null)  {
        $this->radio = '';
        }
    elseif (isset($opts['radio'])) {
        $this->radio = $opts['radio'];    
    } 
}
```

This method shall generate the html tags:

```
public function render() : string
{        
    $out = '';
    $out .= '<fieldset>';
    $out .= '<legend>Choose your monster</legend>';
    $out .= '<input type="' . $this->type . '"';
    $out .= $this->renderRadioChecked();
    $out .= '<label for="' . $this->id . '"' . '>';
    $out .= $this->label . '</label>';
    $out .= '<br/>';
    $out .= '</fieldset>';

    return $out;        
}

protected function renderRadioChecked() 
{
    $out = '';
    if ($this->radio == '') {
    $out .= 'id="' . $this->id . '"' . 'name="' . $this->name . '"' . '>';
        } else {
            $out .= 'id="' . $this->id . '"' . 'name="' . $this->name . '"' . ' checked' . '>';
        }
        return $out;
    }
```

Expected outcome shall be:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Choose your favorite monster</legend>

<input type="radio" id="kraken" name="monster">
<label for="kraken">Kraken</label><br/>

<input type="radio" id="sasquatch" name="monster" checked>
<label for="sasquatch">Sasquatch</label><br/>

<input type="radio" id="mothman" name="monster">
<label for="mothman">Mothman</label>
</fieldset>
```

Full version with radio buttons can be seen here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset

Note:
I do already have a form tag with other html tags on the index page. That´s why I can only generate the fieldset as given here.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the fieldset html since it's not a radio button element. I might think about doing a form class and injecting the radio into that. So, to get multiple radio buttons, after removing the `fieldset` html, loop the radio button class OR you can just allow the radio button class to create more that one radio button at a time:

```
class Radio extends Input
{
    protected $data;

    public function __construct(array $opts)
    {
        parent::__construct($opts);
        # The type is irrelevant since this class is a radio, the type is already known.
        # I would just assign the array to a storage variable
        if(empty($opts)) {
            $this->data = false;
        }
        else {
            # I would make sure the array is going to be consistent
            $this->data = (isset($opts['radio']))? [$opts] : $opts;
        } 
    }

    public function render() : string
    {
        # May as well stop here if empty
        if(empty($this->data))
            return false;
        # Loop your data array
        foreach($this->data as $radio) {
            # Build the input
            $out[] = '<input type="radio" '.$this->createAttrElem($radio).' />';
            # I would check to see if the label is set (you never know)
            if(!empty($radio['label']))
                $out[] = '<label for="'.$radio['id'].'">'.$radio['label'].'</label>';
        }
        # Send back the string
        return implode(PHP_EOL, $out);
    }

    protected function createAttrElem($radio) 
    {
        # See if all these attributes are set first
        if(!empty($radio['id']))
            $attr[] = 'id="'.$radio['id'].'"';
        if(!empty($radio['name']))
            $attr[] = 'name="'.$radio['name'].'"';
        if(!empty($radio['checked']))
            $attr[] = 'checked';
        # Return a string
        return (isset($attr))? implode(' ', $attr) : '';
    }
    /**
     *    @description    I might maybe make this method just run the render method.
     *                    Saves on having to write it out.
     */
    public  function __toString()
    {
        return $this->render();
    }
}
```

The form class could look something like:

```
class Form
{
    protected   $layout,
                $type;
    /**
     *    @description    I would allow the form class to be flexible but set default to "form"
     */
    public  function    __construct($type = 'form')
    {
        $this->type     = $type;
    }
    /**
     *    @description    Create the open tag
     */
    public function open(array $attr)
    {
        $open[] = '<'.$this->type;
        foreach($attr as $key => $value) {
            $open[] = $key.'="'.$value.'"';
        }
        $this->layout[] = implode(' ', $open).'>';
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     *    @description    Here you would add the children of the parent element
     */
    public function addChild($Object)
    {
        $this->layout[] = $Object->render();
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     *    @description    Close the element
     */
    public function close()
    {
        $this->layout[] = '</'.$this->type.'>';
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     *    @description    Create a string of the layout
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return implode(PHP_EOL, $this->layout);
    }
    /**
     *    @description    Shortcut the render process
     **/
    public  function __toString()
    {
        return $this->render();
    }
}
```

Then to use it all:

```
$formConf = [
    'kraken' => [
        'type' => 'radio',
        'id' => 'kraken',
        'name' => 'monster',
        'label' => 'Kraken',
        'radio' => 'checked'
    ],

    'sasquatch' => [
        'type' => 'radio',
        'id' => 'sasquatch',
        'name' => 'monster',
        'label' => 'Sasquatch',
        'radio' => ''
    ],

    'mothman' => [
        'type' => 'radio',
        'id' => 'mothman',
        'name' => 'monster',
        'label' => 'Mothman',
        'radio' => ''
    ]
];

$Fieldset   =   new Form('fieldset');

echo $Fieldset->open(['name' => 'test'])
    ->addChild(new Radio($formConf))
    ->close();
```

This would output:

```
<fieldset name="test">
<input type="radio" id="kraken" name="monster" />
<label for="kraken">Kraken</label>
<input type="radio" id="sasquatch" name="monster" />
<label for="sasquatch">Sasquatch</label>
<input type="radio" id="mothman" name="monster" />
<label for="mothman">Mothman</label>
</fieldset>
```